# Redirect in nginx form port 80 to port 3000 but keeping the url the same

Tags: node.js, nginx, ubuntu-18.04

I have a NodeJS backend running on a server on port 3000
the requests are arriving on port 80
now in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/node` I have the following config

```
server {

listen 80 default_server;


server_name name.example;


return 301 http://195.x.x.x:3000;

}
```

when a request reach the server it redirects to port 3000
but when a request like `http://195.x.x.x/api/test/test`
it also redirects to `http://195.x.x.x:3000`
how can I redirect to port 3000 and keep the same url like `http://195.x.x.x:3000/api/test/test`

Answer (score 3):

Why are you returning a 301 code, if you just want to forward requests and return them through your server you would be better using proxy_pass why are you redirecting them?

You can setup a reverse proxy using NGINX like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name name.example;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass         http://195.x.x.x:3000;
    }
}
```

However if you truly do want to redirect them, you should change `return 301 http://195.x.x.x:3000;` to `return 301 http://195.x.x.x:3000$request_uri;`

Comment: I've tried the first solution and for some reason it didn't work for me so I found the second solution helpful

Comment: @Yaman I think you found that the second solution _worked_, despite it probably not being what you really want. Doing something that works is not always equivalent to doing something the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer right after posting the question it was `$request_uri`
I should have but

```
server {

listen 80 default_server;


server_name name.example;


return 301 http://195.x.x.x:3000$request_uri;
}
```